# Excluding parts of the content for a template

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email-template

I'm creating a custom template with  static content created for other templates. I'm currently trying to use a specific html only based content but would like to exclude an object.

Wondering what would be the best way to do this with out creating another content that is like the current one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can conditionally hide and show content with AMPScript.

```
%%[
var @lang
set @lang = AttributeValue("language")
]%%

<-- some other HTML -->

%%[ if @lang == "es" and @lang != "pt" then ]%%

<h1>Hola</h1>

%%[ elseif @lang == "fr" then ]%%

<h1>Bonjour</h1>

%%[ elseif @lang == "au" then ]%%

<h1>G'day!</h1>

%%[ else ]%%

<h1>Hello</h1>

%%[ endif ]%%
```

Reference: [**AMPScript Syntax Guide**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/)

Comment: Sorry for the edit @Adam, I couldn't help myself. Hey, it's Friday.

Comment: LOL. You can edit my answers anytime.